# say morning evening and afternoon in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i want to create a directive which reurns morning evening and afternoon . If i would code in java script this will be the logic

```
var time = 00;


/* hour is before noon */
if ( time < 12 ) 
{
    document.write("Good Morning!");
}
else  /* Hour is from noon to 5pm (actually to 5:59 pm) */
if ( time >= 12 && time <= 17 )
{
    document.write("Good Afternoon!");
}
else  /* the hour is after 5pm, so it is between 6pm and midnight */
if ( time > 17 && time <= 24 )
{
    document.write("Good Evening!");
}
else  /* the hour is not between 0 and 24, so something is wrong */
{
    document.write("I'm not sure what time it is!");
}
```

How to achieve this in angular using directive

my angular application dom is

```
<p> 12:00:01 </p>
```

i want it to render as `<p>afternoon </p>`

Comment: Looks like a use-case for a custom Filter in my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

I would prefer a filter rather than a directive and its pretty simple to implement like below.

**Filter:**

```
app.filter('greet', function() {
  return function(input) {
    if (input < 12) {
      return 'Good Morning';
    } else if (input >= 12 && input <= 17) {
      return 'Good Afternoon';
    } else if (input > 17 && input <= 24) {
      return 'Good Evening';
    } else {
      return "I'm not sure what time it is!";
    }
  };
});
```

**HTML:** `<span>{{value | greet}}</span>`

**Sample Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/5zs1zrxgeL7OT7ssT7Ak?p=preview